# Kik Reset user permissions

Tags: kik

I wanna do some testing regarding the acception of user permissions.

I am testing via Genymotion and made a Kik Account for my testing purposes. The only problem is that I already gave my app permission to my userdata and I cant find a way to reset this. I don`t want to make a new account everytime I am testing this function.

Is there a way to reset the permission so that I will have to accept again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is functionality for this

1. Open Kik and go to settings (the cog icon in the top bar)
2. Click on Help -> Developers
3. Turn on "Developer mode"
4. Open the webapp you're trying to debug
5. In the sidebar, long press the entry and select "Enable debug mode"

From here on out you can longpress the entry and choose "reset" which will reset the permissions